# Can't minus in sql

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

```
 string sql2 = "UPDATE project_table 
                SET resources=(resources-" + txtresource.Text + ") 
                where code=" + project_code + "";
```

I used the query below to update my table, but it seem my database didn't minus the resources. What did I do wrong?

Comment: what value you are trying to dump in there? and note that you're probably open to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com).

Comment: why don't you convert that into a stored procedure and use variables assignment along with basic mathematical calculations also use parameterized query's vs Concatenated Query's

Comment: The issue seems to be in your own remark below regarding the `decimal`. Can you add your datamodel here? That should show the issue cause

Comment: This is crazy-vulnerable to sql injection. It's practically begging to get hacked.

Comment: Also be sure to check your condition (`code=project_code`). Perhaps it is never true, cause no updates to occur.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert it and then use in query like

```
int val = Convert.ToInt32(txtresource.Text.Trim());
SET resources = resources - val
```

Finally consider using `SQLParameter` for avoiding `SQL Injection Attack`

```
string sql2 = "UPDATE project_table SET resources = resources - @val where code = @code";
//Create Command
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql2, connectionObject);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

cmd.Parameters.Add(SQLDbType.INT, @val).Value = val;
cmd.Parameters.Add(SQLDbType.VARCHAR, @code).Value = project_code;
```

Comment: `Since txtresource.Text data is of string type; performing numerical operation in SQL would fail or error`  I don't see why. The value of txtresource.Text is being treated like literal in SQL.

Comment: i'm using decimal, can I cast it like this? CAST(txtresource.Text As Decimal(10,2)) ?

Comment: @ConradFrix, NO, see OP is doing concatanation in SQL string. the value would get substituted.

Comment: @Rahul what do you think is the value of `sql2` is that is being sent to the db? wouldn't it be something like `UPDATE project_table SET resources=(resources-4 ) where code=533`

Comment: @ConradFrix, yes correct but my doubt is that textbox text is string type and so would be passed as is unless ADO.NET framework cast that to proper type (per column type) and pass it.

Comment: @rounen, better is cast it in your application code and then pass that casted value in SQL string. See edit in answer if that helps.

Comment: MySQL is smart enough to implicitly cast a string to a number when the other data types involved in the expression make it obvious.  Adding (subtracting) a string to a numeric column value will always cast the string to a number.